# Troubleshooting SqlException (0x80131904)

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have been trying to troubleshoot this error for a while now with no success. I was wondering someone can help me begin to identify what might be causing this error.

I tried looking into the php script that is calling it which did not help. In addition, I was unable to locate this path:

```
Inventory1.welcome.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Inventory1\welcome.aspx.cs:55
```

Complete Error Message

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +6256377
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +245
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, SqlConnection owningObject) +6270399
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject) +181
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart) +6271242
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +6271208
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +354
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +703
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +54
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +6272472
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +81
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +1657
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +88
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +6275911
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +258
   Inventory1.welcome.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Inventory1\welcome.aspx.cs:55
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +132
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2428
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an `SqlException`.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

`Page_Load` method of the code behind file of `Welcome.aspx` page is trying to open the connection to your sql-server and it is failing. Check your connection string.

Basically you should give a `valid connection string` to the SqlConnection object before opening it for querying the database. Ex;

```
using(SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("valid_connection_string"))
{
   //Other stuff
   cnn.Open();
   //Execute the command
}
```

[This web site](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) has various different types of connection strings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What is bizarre about the error message described is that `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Inventory1\welcome.aspx.cs:55` is a path on a server that no longer exists. I new `welcome.aspx` path exists, and it seems like sql is trying to access an outdated path.

Comment: It follows, that I don't have access to `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Inventory1\welcome.aspx.cs:55`

Comment: Are you running the site on IIS or Asp.net server? It seems error path is coming from IIS root folder.

Comment: Another option.  Sometimes the error will be given for the path where the code was compiled (in a dll).  Like, our "build machine" builds all our code...and whenever there is an exception about a path about a file, it shows the folder structure from the build machine.  I don't think that is the case here, but throwing in another possibility.

Comment: To isolate the error, you could set a debug point where you trying to Open() the connection and check if the ConnectionString is okay.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a URL on a full write up on Sql Connection debugging.

Your issue could be as simple as a errant password.

OR

It would be that the Sql Server doesn't allow remote connections.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx